# What software to use to generate formatted packing slips from MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, invoice, packing

I need to generate formatted (particularly style) packing slips from a MySQL database.  We are a fulfillment house that is integrating with an internet company.

Comment: that is a very broad question.  Are you looking to write your own, hoping to find something off the shelf, or...?

Comment: Please read the [FAQ] and [ask] to understand why this question is not appropriate for SO.